# SprayJson: Object is missing required member 'User$u0020ID

Tags: spray, spray-json

Here is my Json

```
{"preview":false,"offset":0,"result":{"User ID":"ab192013","IP    
   Address":"101.2.0.11"}}
```

I have two case classes

```
   case class Sample(result: Result)
   case class Result(`User ID` : String , `IP Address`: String)

   object MyResultJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
   implicit val ResultFormat = jsonFormat2(Result.apply)

   implicit def sampleFormat[jsonformat] = jsonFormat1(Sample.apply)
   }
```

I cannot get user ID value

Please help, I get the exception below

```
MalformedContent(Object is missing required member 'User$u0020ID',Some(spray.json.DeserializationException: Object is missing required member 'User$u0020ID'))
```

Comment: This is a bug. Can you please file it at https://github.com/spray/spray-json?